# How to avoid having to use fully qualified name for the Styles.Render method in a Razor view

Tags: c#, razor

I'm trying to implement the Styles.Render method in a project of mine and I am using the separate, pre-built MVC 4 internet application project that's created from the New Project wizard as my model.  In the pre-built MVC website's _Layout.cshtml layout view, the following code appears within the head tag:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

However, in my own project, just using the @Styles.Render syntax does not seem to work. For some reason, the view does not like it. And I have to resort to using the fully qualified version of the method:

```
@System.Web.Optmization.Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

I would like to know what am I missing or how can I avoid having to use the fully qualified type and member syntax from within a Razor view in the manner of the pre-built version as described above?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried building your project and relinking the DLLs?  A lot of the time when I start a new project all of the razor syntax will not be accepted by intellisense until I build the project.

Comment: Yes, I did AgnosticDev. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the System.Web.Optimization namespace reference in the web.config in the views folder

```
<configuration>
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
  <pages basePageType="...">
   <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
   </namespaces>
  </pages>
 </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, @RobertSlaney. That did the trick! Although, at first, when I put the namespace in the web.config file inside the Views folder, the build did not seem to take it (failed). And so, I went up a level higher and put the namespace in the web.config of the root level of the application. That worked and the build was successful.

However, still being curious, I took the namespace out of the root level and put it back again in web.config file of the Views folder. This time, the build did not complain about it. I find this interestingly odd. I kept it in the Views' web.config folder. Thanks.

Comment: Compare your web.config frmo the MVC4 template version.  There might be more namespaces you're missing.